# Query all packages permission

Tags: react-native, permissions

Google Play asks about this permission even though we do not use it in our app. My app cannot be submitted. Is there anyone who can explain what the problem is?

Any help would be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this. Update in policy 20 July.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-query-all-packages-permission%2Cexceptions%2Cinvalid-uses